# only using development mysql db, not test or production in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I've created a new rails app (3.1.1) using MySQL. In database.yml, I've put in the login credentials for a remote MySQL server in development, while the test & production databases are set up with localhost. It appears that creating a scaffold and rake db:migrate goes into the test db?

How do I do force rails to only use development mysql db? I'd like db:create, db:migrate, etc. only create tables in the development (remote MySQL) server and NOT in test or production?

Comment: I'm with sorens, although the answer seems more of a question--what makes you think it's *not* using the dev DB if you don't provide an environment-specific option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rake db:migrate` and similar calls use your `development` environment, not your test one. If you want to migrate your test database, you would do

```
rake RAILS_ENV=test db:migrate
```

How are you determining that when you use `rake db:migrate` that this is going into your test DB?

Comment: Thanks, you were right.

Not sure how I was getting data in my test db the other day